# Inf-compactness for continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, compactness

Consider the continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ where $X$ is a compact countable subset of some euclidean space.

We remind the definition of inf-compactness : a function $f$ is inf-compact if for each $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $\{x\in X|f(x)\leq \lambda\}$ is compact.

I am wondering if from continuity of $f$ and definition of $X$ we can derive that $f$ is inf-compact ?

My guess is that as $X$ is countable we can endow $X$ with discrete topology but I don't know how to proceed next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $X$ is countable or a subset of Euclidean space is not relevant. Because $f$ is continuous, for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ we have that: $$\{x\in X:f(x)\le\lambda\}=f^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])$$Is closed. As a closed subset of a compact space, it is also compact. So $f$ is $\inf$-compact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does it means that any continuous function from any topological space to $\mathbb{R}$ is inf-compact ? You are referencing of a closed subset of a compact space, which compact space do you mean?

Comment: @potfire I mean the compact space $X$. Compactness of $X$ is essential. A counterexample otherwise is the identity function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, this is not $\inf$-compact

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer. Therefore, it would means that any continuous function on a compact set is inf-compact ?

Comment: @potfire Yeah, if $X$ is compact and $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, $f$ will be $\inf$-compact. More than that, it will also be bounded.